# Is it possible to declare "text" and "keyword" on the same field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to both search on a field and aggregate it. Is there any option to declare a field both as text and keyword?

I've read a little bit about multifields. Is that a possible solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Elasticsearch will map text values to a `text` field, with a `keyword` sub-field. Your mapping would look like this:

```json
 "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "newfield": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As a consequence, it will both be possible to perform full-text search on `newfield` and keyword search and aggregations using the `newfield.keyword` field.

Relevant documentation: [Dynamic field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#dynamic-field-mapping)